# Need to change dynamically a dependency injected class in a Restfull Laravel Controller

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5, type-hinting

I'm using Laravel 5 as a framework and I'm facing a problem right now with the type-hint based dependency injection:

I would like to reduce the quantity of {Model}CreateRequest and {ModelUpdateRequest}. To solve that I thought of creating a base BaseController with the common store, update create, destroy methods that other classes will inherit from. Classes like PageController, PostController, NewsController, etc. The problem is, default [Laravel CRUD controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers) have a built dependency injection in methods update and store (classes {Model}CreateRequest and {ModelUpdateRequest} are injected)

How could I dynamically change the class injected in the BaseController?

Comment: What built dependency injection? If you wrote your own `BaseController` you can DI it with your own `BaseCreateRequest`, for instance, and use Laravel `Inversion of Control` container to bind what class it should be.

Comment: Marco Aurélio, could you give an example of using dynamic dependency injection? Thanks!

Comment: @aleixfabra https://gist.github.com/Deleugpn/ff86eb58f345664f51bfeed88f0e7c32